# Blocking version of delay in Celery?

Tags: celery, django-celery

I know this defeats the whole purpose of using Celery, but is there a function that will block until the result has returned?

So instead of `MyTask.delay(some_arg="foo")` where I have to go around and fetch the result could I call `actual_result = MyTask.dont_delay(some_arg="foo")` that will block and just return the result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AsyncResult.get blocks until task is ready, and returns its result:

http://ask.github.com/celery/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.AsyncResult.get

```
result = MyTask.delay(some_arg="foo")
result.get()
```

Answer (score 1):

MyTask.apply will do what you're asking.

Comment: apply method will execute task locally (current process), not in the workers.